# C# StreamWriter.Flush() to local server takes 1 ms, but 13 seconds(!) to remote server

Tags: c#-4.0, network-programming, streamwriter

I have a Java server application and a WPF (C#) client talking to each other over TCP. The server application uses Apache Mina. The client application uses TCPClient as follows:

```
TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient(host, port);
NetworkStream stream = tcp.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
...
writer.WriteLine(data);
writer.Flush();
```

Everything worked a dream until I tried to send large amounts of data (contents of a file) from client to server. If both client and server run on my local machine everything works fine and fast (transfering 1 MB of data takes about 25 ms).

Clarification: Due to buffer size limitations, the maximum amount of data being flushed is 64 KB. I divide the data into blocks no larger than 64 KB.

The problem starts when I try exactly the same thing with local client and remote server (within our corporate network). In that case, a single call to writer.Flush() takes 13 SECONDS (compared to 1 ms in local scenario) which is incredibly slow.

The problem arises ONLY when sending large amounts of data from client to server (although not larger than 64 KB, so not that big). Small chunks are no problem, the other way (server to client) no problem either even with large amounts of data, so the network itself should not be an issue.

Can anyone help? I have no clue ;-)

I tried the following:

- played around with different buffer sizes
- turned off firewalls on both sides

Nothing helped.

Comment: Network speeds could be miserable.  But without you measuring network speeds you won't be able to determine the cause of the slowdown.

Comment: @Will: Could you suggest an easy way (a tool?) to measure network speed in this case?

Comment: Just tested network speed with the tool "LAN Speed Test". Result: The network is quite fast so this is not the issue.

Comment: Look at the virus scanner, from experience this can slow traffic down significantly because it starts inspecting traffic it deems as suspicious. Alternatively try another PC on the network to act as the server or client, or better yet, try a 2nd pc and use a mini hub or switch to connect the 2 PCs. If that works well then try it on the corp. network. Basically I recommend keep trying different scenarios until you add that one piece that causes the problem.

Comment: @Igor: Thx, virus scanner is a good idea, I will check this.

Comment: I checked the virus scanner issue. There is no virus scanner involved.